# Implementing audit trail ms sql using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

My application would be like having category and under category, products will be there.

Three types of admin will be there. super admin (more than one admin will be available), product admin (more than one product admin) and user.

Super admin and product admin can add/delete/update product. User can view that.

Super admin and product admin can change the user permission.

Super admin can add users.

For this I need to add audit trail.

I have referred some sites like best way to implement an audit trail in sql-server?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21068/Audit-Trail-Generator-for-Microsoft-SQL

http://techbrij.com/audit-trail-microsoft-sql-server-quickly

**My understanding from this.** 
This will write the audit trail whatever (based on our setting) action done to the table
For each table we need to have separate shadow table.
I have planned for the following implementation

I have audit trail types with the predefined message. For example I am having the following tables **AuditTrailActions** and **AuditTrailMessages**. My message template would be like the following,

> Product {ProductName} [{PersonId}] has been created by {Username}
>   [{PersonId}]

Whenever the product is added successfully, I will call a stored procedure from there will call audit trail messages table to get the message and replace the necessary tags and update in AuditTrail Table

I will do like the same thing for all the actions.

**Will be a good implementation?
If not can anyone suggest good implementation for my need?**

Comment: SQL Server 2016 includes Temporal Tables, which keeps track of all changes to your table in a separate history table. The implementation is the same under the covers as using a trigger.

Comment: @RandolphWest TT don't include user information though, which makes it somewhat limited in the scope of auditing.

Answer (score 1):

Some native options:

- [Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Server Audit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) (if you also want to audit reads)

Both are Enterprise Edition features.